# Pandas dataframe Groupby and retrieve date range

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Here is my dataframe that I am working on. There are two pay periods defined:
first 15 days and last 15 days for each month.

```
         date  employee_id hours_worked   id job_group  report_id
0  2016-11-14            2         7.50  385         B         43
1  2016-11-15            2         4.00  386         B         43
2  2016-11-30            2         4.00  387         B         43
3  2016-11-01            3        11.50  388         A         43
4  2016-11-15            3         6.00  389         A         43
5  2016-11-16            3         3.00  390         A         43
6  2016-11-30            3         6.00  391         A         43
```

I need to group by employee_id and job_group but at the same time
I have to achieve date range for that grouped row.

For example grouped results would be like following for employee_id 1:

### Expected Output:

```
         date  employee_id hours_worked  job_group  report_id
1  2016-11-15            2         11.50        B         43
2  2016-11-30            2         4.00         B         43
4  2016-11-15            3         17.50        A         43
5  2016-11-16            3         9.00         A         43
```

Is this possible using pandas dataframe groupby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SM`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) with [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) and last add [`SemiMonthEnd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

d = {'hours_worked':'sum','report_id':'first'}
df = (df.groupby(['employee_id','job_group',pd.Grouper(freq='SM',key='date', closed='right')])
       .agg(d)
       .reset_index())

df['date'] = df['date'] + pd.offsets.SemiMonthEnd(1)
print (df)
   employee_id job_group       date  hours_worked  report_id
0            2         B 2016-11-15          11.5         43
1            2         B 2016-11-30           4.0         43
2            3         A 2016-11-15          17.5         43
3            3         A 2016-11-30           9.0         43
```

Comment: Ok tried but somehow its not working with data set i had provided.

Comment: @Kishan - Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? Or more data rows with expected output?

Comment: First row data is 2016-11-14 which should come under 2016-11-15 bracket but it went to 2016-10-31 bracket

Answer (score 1):

a. First, (for each `employee_id`) use [multiple `Grouper`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52187944/4057186) with the `.sum()` on the `hours_worked` column. Second, use [`DateOffset`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19820387/4057186) to achieve bi-weekly `date` column. After these 2 steps, I have assigned the `date` in the grouped DF based on 2 brackets (date ranges) - if [`day of month` (from the `date` column)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.day.html) is <=15, then I set the `day` in `date` to 15, else I set the `day` to 30. This `day` is then used to assemble a new [`date`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37103131/4057186). I calculated month end day based on [1](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offset-semantics), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37354256/4057186).

b. (For each `employee_id`) get the [`.last()` record](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15002718/4057186) for the `job_group` and `report_id` columns

c. merge a. and b. on the `employee_id` key

```
# a.
hours = (df.groupby([
            pd.Grouper(key='employee_id'),
            pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='SM')
                    ])['hours_worked']
            .sum()
            .reset_index())
hours['date'] = pd.to_datetime(hours['date'])
hours['date'] = hours['date'] + pd.DateOffset(days=14)

# Assign day based on bracket (date range) 0-15 or bracket (date range) >15
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
hours['bracket'] = hours['date'] + MonthEnd(0)
hours['bracket'] = pd.to_datetime(hours['bracket']).dt.day
hours.loc[hours['date'].dt.day <= 15, 'bracket'] = 15
hours['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dict(year=hours['date'].dt.year,
                                    month=hours['date'].dt.month,
                                    day=hours['bracket']))
hours.drop('bracket', axis=1, inplace=True)

# b.
others = (df.groupby('employee_id')['job_group','report_id']
            .last()
            .reset_index())

# c.
merged = hours.merge(others, how='inner', on='employee_id')
```

Raw data for `employee_id==1` and `employeeid==3`

```
df.sort_values(by=['employee_id','date'], inplace=True)
print(df[df.employee_id.isin([1,3])])

    index       date  employee_id  hours_worked   id job_group  report_id
0       0 2016-11-14            1           7.5  481         A         43
10     10 2016-11-21            1           6.0  491         A         43
11     11 2016-11-22            1           5.0  492         A         43
15     15 2016-12-14            1           7.5  496         A         43
25     25 2016-12-21            1           6.0  506         A         43
26     26 2016-12-22            1           5.0  507         A         43
6       6 2016-11-02            3           6.0  487         A         43
4       4 2016-11-08            3           6.0  485         A         43
3       3 2016-11-09            3          11.5  484         A         43
5       5 2016-11-11            3           3.0  486         A         43
20     20 2016-11-12            3           3.0  501         A         43
21     21 2016-12-02            3           6.0  502         A         43
19     19 2016-12-08            3           6.0  500         A         43
18     18 2016-12-09            3          11.5  499         A         43
```

Output

```
print(merged)

    employee_id       date  hours_worked job_group  report_id
0             1 2016-11-15           7.5         A         43
1             1 2016-11-30          11.0         A         43
2             1 2016-12-15           7.5         A         43
3             1 2016-12-31          11.0         A         43
4             2 2016-11-15          31.0         B         43
5             2 2016-12-15          31.0         B         43
6             3 2016-11-15          29.5         A         43
7             3 2016-12-15          23.5         A         43
8             4 2015-03-15           5.0         B         43
9             4 2016-02-29           5.0         B         43
10            4 2016-11-15           5.0         B         43
11            4 2016-11-30          15.0         B         43
12            4 2016-12-15           5.0         B         43
13            4 2016-12-31          15.0         B         43
```

Comment: This answers is updated based on new data and explanation provided in comments section of OP - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53007338/pandas-dataframe-groupby-and-retrieve-date-range#comment92921634_53008199) - direct source for new data is [here](https://pastebin.com/tdCStypW).